# replace amazon associates link builder shotcodes in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress

While amazon is stopping it's own wordpress plugin by March 2020, I was moving towards another and found a pretty good one. But afaik none supports migration of the old amazon_link and amazon_textlink shortcodes to their own shortcode format. As I used it quite a few hundred times along the past years, it is impossible to replace them by hand.
Thus, I came up with the idea of using regular expressions.
What I have now in wordpress posts is something like:

```
lorem ipsum blabla</p>
<p>[amazon_link asins='B07ZGG8WB5,B005LD2IWE' template='template' store='somecode-21' marketplace='DE' link_id='acd3b40d-de6f-4e2d-825e-56eabdaf44b5']</p>
<p>lorem ipsum...
```

where at least one ASIN (e.g. `B07ZGG8WB5`) must be present and multiple are just separated by a comma.
So what I got up to now is this regex

```
\[amazon_link asins='([A-Z0-9]{10}(?:,[A-Z0-9]{10})*)' [^]]*\]
```

which, from what I can see in (online) regex tools, works fine recognizing just the amazon link content and put the ASINs into a capture group.
But here I am stuck. What can I do now to replace everything matched *outside* the capturing group so in the end, I get

```
[amazon box="B07ZGG8WB5,B005LD2IWE"/]
```

in these posts? and is this possible in MYSQL diretly or should it be done in a separate php?

Comment: What version of MySQL?  You need 8.0 to have `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.  Without that, it would be easier to use PHP.

Comment: I use 5.7 so I would need to go for php?

Comment: PHP has always(?) had a good `preg_replace(...)` function.

Comment: that's for sure. so because mysql installation is too old, I will head for php